# Why the i and j of the cofactor here is not $C_{ij}$ but $C_{ji}$ instead?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why the cofactor here is not $C_{ij}$ but $C_{ji}$ instead?

[image]

Comment: What... are you asking for the whole proof?  I hate to tell you "*it just is because...*" but instead of that, how about I ask "Why do you find that strange?"  You seem to be linking a portion of a screenshot of a book, and this is the fourth in a series of formulae used in the definition or theorem.  Read again the rest of that page from the beginning of the calculations.

Comment: @ JMoravitz I think I got some clue now, but see if you agree with my thoughts. From Cramer's rule, we have the formula $x_{i}=\frac{det(A_{i}b)}{dee(A)}$ and $det(A_{i}b)) =C_{i j}= (-1)^{i+j}det(A)$ the cofactor. however, from the insert picture, the cofactor is $C_{j,i}$ instead. I finally realize that this is the inverse of A that it is trying to solve, so $A^{-1}A=I$ therefore, $xi=\frac{det(A_{i}e_{j})}{det(A)}$. then for example to find $ x_{i}$, I am finding the the rows of $A^{-1}$, each row is the weights to A in $A^{-1}A=I$, so it has to be transposed,

Comment: @ JMoravitz this is why the cofactor C is switched to $C_{ji}$ am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this excerpt as from David C. Lay's Linear Algebra and Its Applications.
In his proof, which involves Cramer's Rule, he takes the cofactor expansion down the column rather than the row, hence the reversal of subscripts.
Why do you think he takes the expansion down the $i^{th}$ column?

Comment: @ guppy @ JMoravitz I think I got some clue now, but see if you agree with my thoughts. From Cramer's rule, we have the formula $x_{i}=\frac{det(A_{i}b)}{dee(A)}$ and $det(A_{i}b)) =C_{i j}= (-1)^{i+j}det(A)$ the cofactor. however, from the insert picture, the cofactor is $C_{j,i}$ instead. I finally realize that this is the inverse of A that it is trying to solve, so $A^{-1}A=I$ therefore, $xi=\frac{det(A_{i}e_{j})}{det(A)}$. then for example to find $ x_{i}$, I am finding the the rows of $A^{-1}$, each row is the weights to A in $A^{-1}A=I$, so it has to be transposed,

Comment: @ guppy this is why the cofactor C is switched to $C_{ji}$ am I on the right track?